# Setting CheckboxBar defaults under Manipulate

Tags: manipulate, gui-construction

How is the default for the checkboxes created by `CheckboxBar` in a `Manipulate` set to be checked instead of unchecked?  (The number of checkboxes may be variable.)

Comment: Would you please give an example of the code you are working on?

Comment: Generally speaking, all controls are set to the initial value(s) of the variables, if any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify an initial value to a variable captured by a Manipulate construct. In your particular case, you could do something like this:

```
Manipulate[Total[x], {{x, Range[5]}, Range[5], ControlType -> CheckboxBar}]
```

This creates a CheckboxBar control with five checkboxes all preset to the checked state.  The values in the CheckboxBar do not need to be integers.

```
With[{zooList = {"Cow", "Walrus", "Zebra", "Lion"}}, 
 Manipulate[
  If[Length[x] === 0, "I want to see nothing at the zoo.", 
   StringJoin[{"I want to see a ", Riffle[x, ", "], 
     " at the zoo."}]], {{x, zooList}, zooList, 
   ControlType -> CheckboxBar}]]
```

Answer (score 3):

Initialization for `CheckboxBar` works pretty much as for any type of control.

```
{{checkBoxes, initial-checked-values, ""}, value-list, ControlType -> CheckboxBar}]
```

For example,

```
Manipulate[Row[{"Boxes checked: ", Length@checkBoxes}],
  {{checkBoxes, {1, 3}, ""}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, ControlType -> CheckboxBar}]
```

will produce the following initial state when evaluated.

[image: manipulate]